# body fixed, container can't align the center

Tags: html, css

```
<style>
body{margin:0; padding:0; position:fixed; }
#container{width:1024; height:768px; background:#ccc; margin:0 auto;}
</style>

<body>
<div id="container"></div>
</body>
```

I have create a pop Box by myself, when user click & open the box. I use jquery to set body `position:fixed`

My problem is when body set fixed, the contain wont align the center (`margin:0 auto`)

is any way to solve this problem

Comment: You shouldn't use `position: fixed;` on the `body`, for some reason if you want to use, than consider using it on a `div` element nested inside `body`

Comment: `position:fixed;` in `body` will make your content unscrollable mate...you want that for your page!! :o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for your case., giving `width` to body should work.

```
<style>
body{width: 100%; margin:0; padding:0; position:fixed; }
#container{width:1024px; height:768px; background:#ccc; margin:0 auto;}
</style>

<body>
   <div id="container"></div>
</body>
```

p.s: By the way, why do you want to apply `position:fixed` to `body`? just curious to know!

Comment: hi thx a lot, it works, the reason i add fixed, so 1.background stay same position 2.user cant scroll the background (include ipad)

Comment: okay :) Btw, to fix background.. you could have used `background-position: fixed` as well I think.

Comment: @BenWong : for that...you can use `background-position:fixed`...no need to keep `body:fixed`

Comment: its not real background, actually i try to lock all content inside of body

Answer (score 1):

Create a wrapper

HTML

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="container"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper { 
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 100%; 
text-align: center; 
}

#container { 
display: inline-block; // this is important, need this so it obeys the wrapper text-align: center rule
width:1024; 
height:768px; 
background:#ccc; 
margin:0 auto; 
text-align: left;   // add this if you have text you don't want centered
 }
```